# Is there a segment of users who have flash enabled but javascript disabled?

Tags: accessibility

When making websites accessible, I usually assume that if someone doesn't have javascript, they don't have flash either. Is this true, or is there a group of users who don't have javascript but who would still benefit from flash embedded directly into the page?

I realise that it's technically possible, but I would like to find out whether there is a meaningful quantity of users in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Sure they will be a segment of users with such a configuration, but I suppose it will be very small. Only user which are afraid lots about their privacy disable javascript. These users will never install flash if they aren't forced to do so.

Comment: Other groups of users who browse without JS are those with browsers that don't support it, like for example text-based browsers, those for whom it creates accessibility problems http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/ajax-screenreaders-work and others. Those users often won't use flash either, but privacy and security are hardly the only reason to disable JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) then you may not have to code explicitly for this particular (and probably vanishingly small) demographic.

Comment: Progressive enhancement supposes a hierarchy of capabilities. In the case of having flash but not javascript we can't do naive "progressive enhancement" because there's no clear progression. What's the first layer of enhancement? Flash? Js?